# How to update the app on app-store without new version?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, app-store

I have uploaded an app on app-store. And I have just forget to remove an alert in it. Now I want just to update the old app without new version. So please help me to do this.

Comment: No way, You need to resubmit the binary for review with higher version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the version you uploaded is not yet approved and is still in review, you can go to the 'Binary Details' page and 'Reject the Binary' Then the status of your app will change to 'Developer Rejected'. In this case you can re-upload the new binary having the same version number.

If the version is already approved, you'll only have to create a new version.

Answer (score 9):

You can't. You must submit a new version for review. This new version must have a higher version number than the current version. There is no way to simply update an app.

Answer (score 2):

There's only two ways in which you can upload the same app on App Store:

- Upload a new version.
- You'll have to delete your old app and upload
  the new one. In this your waiting queue will start from the day one. For example: if you've uploaded your app 2 days before and if you remove it now and upload the new build you are back to day 0 and you'll have to wait for 7 more days.

Uploading a new version is the good idea if your Alert is not very critical.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I have upload my new version 1 day before and status is waiting for review. And now from where I can delete this version and upload the new binary.

Comment: Itunes Connect - Manage Your Application - App Details - Binary Details. There you'll get an option to Discar/Delete binary. And then you can re-upload the new binary.

Comment: Hahaha.. What was that @user1652551